# Database Design for Multi-Level Ownership

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I'm trying to figure out what sort of database and what sort of database structure would make sense for representing ownership of different assets by different constituencies.

Say a group of 5 friends get together to invest.  They each make a different contribution and pool it into two Funds.  The two Funds put money in various accounts to purchase stocks and bonds while investing in other assets directly.
So the entities are:

**Owners:**
Friend1,
Friend2,
Friend3,
Friend4,
Friend5

**Pooled Fund:**
Fund1,Fund2.

**Accounts:**
Account1,
Account2,
Account3.

**Instruments:**
Stock1,
Stock2,
Bond1,
Bond2,
Cash,
Other3

So a scenario would be: 
1) Friend1 through Friend3 invest in Fund1 which has Account1 and Account2 and Account1 buys Stock1 and Bond1, Account2 buys Stock1, Stock2, Bond1, Bond2, and Other. 
2) Friend4 and Friend5 invest in both Fund1 and Fund2 and Fund2 owns different things than Fund 1.

**Questions to answer:**

1) How much of Stock 1 does Friend4 have on a look-through basis? What is his "exposure?"

2) Is it possible to create income statement, balance sheet and cashflow statement at each level in the chain based on the proportional ownership of the instruments?

3) Given that the group of Friends may change over time and the Instruments change over time, what is the best way to capture the changes so that it is possible to see who owned what and when?

Comment: Are you familiar with any particular DBMS; i.e. do you have experience with one or more?

Comment: Chapter 20 of Enterprise Model Patterns by Hay discusses this scenario. You can get a free week subscription on safari books online to view it

Comment: It looks like the book Enterprise Model Patterns by Hay doesn't contemplate modeling a transaction across multiple entities with interlocking ownership for varying exposures at each entity.